# What is the Name of this Point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, terminology, roots, graphing-functions

I am trying to find the name of the point at which the derivative of a function at that point is zero but it is not a local max or min within any interval. For instance, take the function $y=(x+1)(x-1)^3$. The roots of the first derivative are -0.5, one, and one but the function at $x=1$ is neither a local max or a local min. What is the name of this point? Is it just a Point of Inflection or is there another name?
[[image: <span class=]$y=(x+1)(x-1)^3$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxanE.png)

Comment: 'Point of Inflection' is pretty much the canonical name.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: A point of inflection is where the tangent line crosses the curve.

Comment: I have heard some people call it a "Plateau", but maybe that's just me

Comment: Also called [inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A colleague of mine from the late 1990s](https://www.lsmsa.edu/news-detail?pk=1345969) used the term **terrace point** for a point $x=a$ where the first derivative is zero and the first derivative doesn't change sign as you pass through $x=a,$ and I liked the idea so much that I subsequently used it in all my calculus classes. Of course, this was only used in simple introductory calculus examples where the zeros of the derivative are isolated from each other.

A few years later (in July 2002; see *6. TERRACE POINTS IN THE FIRST DERIVATIVE TEST* [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/TpC_fn-MkU4/m/QW0IXAWhqf4J)) I was told that the term "terrace point" is in [Ostebee/Zorn's Calculus book](https://www.worldcat.org/title/calculus-from-graphical-numerical-and-symbolic-points-of-view-single-variable/oclc/57669126/editions?referer=di&editionsView=true), although I've never looked at a copy to be sure, and I don't know whether the term was in both the 1994 1st and 2002 2nd editions or only in the 2002 2nd edition.

Anyway, when I last wrote about this term (as far as I can recall), there wasn't nearly as much on the internet as there is now, and google-books searching wasn't available. [A google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22terrace+point%22+%22calculus%22&filter=0) shows that the term "terrace point" is now fairly widely used. Also, [a google-books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22terrace+point%22+%22calculus%22&tbm=bks) shows that it is definitely used in the 2002 2nd edition of Ostebee/Zorn's book, as well as in several other books. Interestingly, the term also appears on [p. 40 (line −10) of William Richard Ransom's 1915 **Early Calculus**](https://books.google.com/books?id=Yx4qAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA40). As far as I can determine, the only use of "terrace point" in one of the math oriented Stack Exchanges is [this answer from 24 October 2019](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3407184/13130).

One of the reasons I liked having a name for this this notion is that it allows you to label all four of the possibilities that can show up on a first derivative sign chart where the derivative is zero (and isolated from the other zeros):

$$ ++++0++++ \;\;\;\;\; \text {ter} $$

$$ ++++0----  \;\;\;\;\; \text {max} $$

$$ ----0++++  \;\;\;\;\; \text {min} $$

$$ ----0----  \;\;\;\;\; \text {ter} $$